# fcm background ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, notifications, cordova-plugin-fcm

i am using FCM in ionic 3
I am getting notification properly when the app is in foreground. When I receive a notification in background, on tapping of notification i am getting the data. But i want to get the data without tapping on the notification. For example see the below code.

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  if(data.wasTapped){
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});
```

So, my problem is to get data in background without tapping the notification

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle fcm background notification without tapping on it in ionic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946934/how-to-handle-fcm-background-notification-without-tapping-on-it-in-ionic-3)