# How to handle fcm background notification without tapping on it in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugin-fcm

i am using FCM in ionic 3. I am getting notification properly when the app is in foreground. When I receive a notification in background i am getting the data in the notification only after tapping the notification. But i want to get the data without tapping on the notification. For example see the below code.

```
this.fcm.onNotification().subscribe(data => {
  if(data.wasTapped){
    console.log("Received in background");
  } else {
    console.log("Received in foreground");
  };
});
```

Here i am getting data if data.wasTrapped is true else in the foreground.
My problem is to get data without tapping the notification when the app is in background